# Export-Import Android Studio AVD's

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I have been developing in Android Studio and have created a number of AVD's which suit my different app specifications. Now i am planning to do a system restore on my PC. 
Is there a way to backup the AVD's and then import them on the new Android Studio installation, after i perform the system restore?

Thanks

Comment: They are just virtual machines... If you can find the SD card image, then yes, you can back them up. Otherwise, I don't understand why you want this because you can just install the apps again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AVD's are stored in the folder:

- On Windows XP: *C:\Documents and Settings\.android*
- On Windows Vista and higher: *C:\Users\.android*
- On Linux / Mac: *~/.android/avd*