# Can I export and share my Google Developer Screen Sizes?

Tags: google-developer-tools

Under "Emulated Devices" I've added a specific set of screen sizes. I would like to share these with someone so they can simply load them into their Google Developer Tools screen sizes. Is there some way to do that?

Comment: The same question have been asked/answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314406/export-import-android-studio-avds/39314583

Comment: Already asked elsewhere